# what does it mean "I'm in up to my wrist"

Tags: meaning

In seinfeld "The pick" episode,

GEORGE: So the minute I started up the steps to her apartment I knew I made a terrible mistake. Going back with her. So we're in her apartment she goes into the bathroom. I'm cursing myself; now how do I get out of this? Then it hits me like a bolt of lightening. The pick.

JERRY: The pick?

ELAINE: The pick?

GEORGE: She comes out of the bathroom, I'm in up to my wrist. You should have seen the look on her face.

What does George mean by "I'm in up to my wrist", it's not about picking nose, is it? How can picking nose be as deep as up to one's wrist? Then what is it?

Comment: It is about picking his nose, and it's an example of [hyperbole](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole). (In other words, this is *Seinfeld*, it's a *joke*.) By the way, our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com), will get you much more detailed (and numerous!) answers to these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of telling the woman that he wants to leave, George turns the situation around so that *she* will ask *him* to leave. He does this by picking his nose and disgusting her. Using *wrist* is an exaggeration to show how truly disgusting he made this.